# Aflresco how to install add ons jar file ? eg. I have to install add on :fme-datalist-extension-share.jar

Tags: java, alfresco

I have to install data list extension in the Alfresco 4.0. I have two file :

1. fme-datalist-extension-share.jar
2. fme-datalist-extension-repository.jar

   so now how can I install this add ons, could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put fme-datalist-extension-repository.jar in

```
your/path/to/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/
```

fme-datalist-extension-share.jar should be in

```
your/path/to/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/lib/
```

Don't forget to restart.